# Error- error validating data: apiVersion not set

Tags: istio

i am trying to deploy a virtual service applying my file istio-routing.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: whitelabel-v1-v2-svc-shift-ftbo
  namespace: whitelabel
spec:
  hosts:
    - whitelabel-v2-ftbo-staging.whitelabel.svc.cluster.local
  gateways:
    - mesh
  http:
    - name: "v1-route"
      match:
        - headers:
            cookie:
              regex: ^(.*;.?|)(wl-site-version=1)(;.*|)$
      route:
        - destination:
            host: nginx-cache.whitelabel.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8080
    - name: "v2-route"
      match:
        - headers:
            cookie:
              regex: ^(.*;.?|)(wl-site-version=2)(;.*|)$
      route:
        - destination:
            host: nginx-cache-v2.whitelabel.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8082
    - name: "default-split-v1-v2-routing"
      route:
        - destination:
            host: nginx-cache.whitelabel.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8080
          headers:
            response:
              add:
                set-cookie: "wl-site-version=1; Path=/"
          weight: 0
        - destination:
            host: nginx-cache-v2.whitelabel.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8082
          headers:
            response:
              add:
                set-cookie: "wl-site-version=2; Path=/"
          weight: 100
```

but getting the below error
`error: error validating "02-istio-routing.yaml": error validating data: apiVersion not set; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

Not sure whats wrong as the other virtual services in the file have the same apiVersion. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

i have check if there is any typo, but all looks good to me.

Comment: The shared virtual service definition is proper.  the error you are getting while using kubectl command.  Trust you are using following command to apply kubectl apply -f istio-routing.yaml instead of kubectl apply -f .